Angular app with nx v16 freezing screen when route.navigate
I have a application called imcl-app. From then i lazy loaded some modules, like this:
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'auth',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('@imcl-scheduling/libraries/auth/feature-auth').then((m) => m.LibrariesAuthFeatureAuthModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'schedule',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('@imcl-scheduling/libraries/scheduler/feature-scheduler').then((m) => m.LibrariesSchedulerFeatureSchedulerModule),
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}

The routes are working normally, but when i call another route with route.navigate, looks like exists some delay to hide de previous page and show de next.
  navigateToSignupPage(eventResponse: string) {
    if(eventResponse === AUTH_EVENT.ON_SIGNUP_CLICK) {
      this.router.navigate([APPLICATION_ROUTES.SIGNUP]);
    }
  }


any one knows how to fix it?
